# Grails - Forked Grails VM exited with error when compiling

Tags: grails, compiler-errors, grails-2.4

It happens when grails tries to compile the project, when --stacktrace and --verbose are used it shows the same output. I tried to reinstall the plugins and grails.
I'm using grails 2.4.3

Here's the error:

```
Running without daemon...
Compiling 230 source files
Parent process shutdown. Exiting...
Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you don't know what is wrong. In order to find the real problem I recommend you change in *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy* the parameter: grails.project.fork for this:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    compile: false,
    test: false,
    run: false,
    war: false,
    console: false
]
```

Try again and you will see the real problem.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that a submodule wasn't initialized thus a class was not found.

Answer (score 0):

*grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,It may be some database problem check whether you have a correct dump or go to C:\Users\Your-pc.grails\2.4.4\ and delete the .slcache folder and retry running the application again.

Answer (score 0):

First time when I faced this error I delete project and imported again. It resolved.
Next time I deleted target forder and files from. m2 folder. It worked.